# Retrieve a parameter inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a jsp which contains a html form. Inside it there is an iframe.
Is there a way to retrieve a parameter that is inside that iframe?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://ajaxpatterns.org/IFrame_Call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such situation, you can only use JavaScript to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can via JavaScript.

Here is how I would do that using jQuery (JavaScript library):

```
$('#someForm iframe').contents().find('input[name=myinputbox]').val();
```

This selects the iframe from within a form with `id="someForm"` and then gets the value of an input field with `name="myinputbox"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form inside the iframe, it's handled like every other form and may be sent via a submit-button, which transfers all given parameter.

If you try to access the iframe-contents from the outer html-page(-form), then (as buaastorm already suggested) you may only use JavaScript to do so…